# Global and Specific error handling AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, error-handling

I've got global handling as follows.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {

        200: function(res, status, xhr) {
        },
        500: function() {
        },

        400: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },
});
```

I do specific handling in backbone model fetch as below.

```
var xhr = byBackbone.fetch({//or save
    success: function(){}, 
    error: function(){
    if(xhr.statusCode == 400 && xhr.data == "some specific response"){
       //specefic handling
    } else {
      //how to call statusCode.400() here or how to leave it for getting handled globally?
    }
    }
});
```

So as in comment, question is, how to leave it for getting handled globally after catching specific error?

Answer (score 1):

Probably -

```
var cb = $.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {

        200: function(res, status, xhr) {
        },
        500: function() {
        },

        400: function() {
        }
}});

cb.statusCode[400](); // put this in your backbone ajax response handler
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/rFhRW/1/

Comment: And how do I pass `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {` params to 400 function?